# Performance issue in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cifilter, ciimage

I have a `UICollectionView` whose items contain an `imageview` on which I am applying CIFilters. So there are about 12 items that are generated but as I scroll items in collection view there is a little glitch when new item is generated.
Is there any way to configure items of `UICollectionView` without this delay.

Currently I am applying filters in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method of `UICollectionView`.

```
// filters array
let arrayOfCIFilters = ["CIBumpDistortionLinear","CIPixellate","CISepiaTone","CITwirlDistortion","CIUnsharpMask","CIVignette","CIPhotoEffectNoir","CIColorInvert","CIMotionBlur","CIColorClamp","CIToneCurve","CIColorPosterize","CICircularScreen"]


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("c1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! filterImagesCollectionViewCell

    let ciImage = CIImage(image:originalImage)
    ciFilter = CIFilter(name: arrayOfCIFilters[indexPath.row])!
    ciFilter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    cell.imageVIew.image = UIImage(CGImage: ciContext.createCGImage(ciFilter.outputImage!, fromRect: ciFilter.outputImage!.extent))
    cell.nameLabel.text = arrayOfCIFilters[indexPath.row]
    return cell                 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating CIImage, CIFilter, UIImage each time the cell is viewed. Remember that cellForItemAtIndexPath is called whenever the cell is currently being displayed so when the user scrolls and come back then this function is executed again.

You should create all the images once in the init() method and save them in the array. Then use that images within this function to display them.

Comment: If i create an array of images in init() method, will the array be not holding many images as i have a single image to filter on.

Comment: Yes it will be holding it. But it's better than to create images each time. This will be cleared/garbage-collected when the parent controller is cleared, for example if you are displaying UICollectionView in UIViewController so when UIViewController is cleared the UICollectionView with it's variables are also cleared.

Comment: sure that will definitely help!

Comment: Good luck. Mark the answer as correct if it helped you.